# How to get list of entities from one table away in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

Consider this schema

```
Hospital
----------
  id
  name
  email
  phone

Department
----------
  id
  name
  email
  phone

Relation
----------
  relationId
  Hospital_Id
  Department_id
```

Here `each` hospital has `many` departments. So `Hospital` has a `OneToMany` relation to `Departments`. `Hospital` table has list of hospitals. `Department` table has list of departments. `Relation` table joins them. There is no foreign key used anywhere.

Now consider these pojos(removed unnecessary stuff for brevity)

```
public class Hospital {
    ...

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="Hospital_ID")
    private Set<Relation> relations;

    ...
}

public class Department{
    ...

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="Department_ID")
    private Set<Relation> relations;

    ...
}

public class Relation{
    ...

    @Id
    @Column(name = "relationId")
    private int relationId;

    @Column(name = "Hospital_ID")
    private int hospitalId;    

    @Column(name = "Department_ID")
    private int departmentId;    
    ...
}
```

So my question is how do I get list(or set) of departments for any given hospital? That is I want to implement this method in `Hospital` pojo

```
public Set<Departments> getDepartments() {
    // Return set of departments corresponding to this(object) hospital
}
```

And also how do I get the opposite of this that is how do I get corresponding hospital object in Department class?

Comment: I have working hibernate code in my eclipse. Not sure how the one-to-many request affects it. If you dont find the answer you need, I can show you my implementation.

Answer (score -1):

There you go. Hope it helps. Cheers!

Edit: Hibernate cfg file is in:

> "rootDir\bin\hibernate.cfg.xml"

```
public class EntityManager
{
    // Creates a factory, that creates sessions.
    private SessionFactory factory;

    /**
     * Constructor. Initially connect to the database.
     */
    public EntityManager()
    {
        this.factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
            .buildSessionFactory();
    }

    /**
     * Closes the session factory.
     */
    public void close()
    {
        this.factory.close();
    }

    /**
     * Loads the objects of your entity from the database.
     */
    public List<YourEntity> loadEntities()
    {
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

        try
        {
            session.beginTransaction();
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Query<YourEntity> createQuery = session
                .createQuery("from YourEntity");
            List<YourEntity> result = createQuery.list();

            session.getTransaction()
                .commit();
            return result;
        }
        finally
        {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Loads entity by id.
     */
    public EntityA loadEntity(long entityId)
    {
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
        try
        {
            session.beginTransaction();
            EntityA entity = session.get(EntityA.class, entityId);

            return entity;
        }
        finally
        {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Saves your entity to database.
     */
    public void saveEntity(YourEntityA entityA)
    {
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
        try
        {
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(entityA);
            session.getTransaction()
                .commit();
        }
        finally
        {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```